# Theorem: Trust-Region Dogleg method

Tags: optimization

The following is part of an assignment so please no full answers.

I am trying to prove the following theorem. In the Dogleg method we consider

$$ p^u = - \frac{g^Tg}{g^TBg}g $$

and

$$ p(\tau) = \tau p^u $$

for $0\leq \tau \leq 1$.

Now, let $B$ be positive definite:

(1) $||p(\tau)||$ is a increasing function of $\tau$

(2) $m(p(\tau))$ is a decreasing function of $\tau$, where $m$ is simply the quadratic model.

The following is what I came up with.

(1) $||p(\tau)||$

Consider the function $h(\tau) = \frac{1}{2}||\tau p^u||^2$:

$$ h(\tau) = \frac{1}{2} \tau ^2 \left\Vert \frac{g^Tg}{g^TBg}g \right\Vert ^2 .$$

If we take the derivative we obtain:

$$ h'(\tau) = \tau \left\Vert \frac{||g||^2}{||g||_B^2}g \right\Vert ^2 = C||g||^2.$$

With $C$ being a positive constant. Therefore the derivative is positive. But, and this is the same problem I have with the second part, this quantity can be $0$, since $\tau$ can be $0$.

(2) $m(p(\tau))$

And this case I study the following expression:

$$ m(\tau p^u) = \frac{1}{2} (\tau p^u)^TB\tau p^u + \tau g^Tp^u .$$

With some computations, I obtain:

$$ m(\tau p^u) = \frac{1}{2}\tau ^2 \frac{||g||^4}{||g||_B^2} - \tau \frac{||g||^4}{||g||_B^2} .$$

Again, we take the derivative and obtain:

$$ m'(\tau p^u) = \frac{||g||^4}{||g||_B^2} \left( \tau -1 \right) .$$

In this case, if $\tau = 0$ we obtain a negative quantity, but when $\tau=1$ we obtain $0$. Am I missing something? *Decreasing function* or *increasing function* means also derivative equal to $0$?

Comment: If $f'>0$ on the interval except for a finite number of isolated points where $f'=0$ then $f$ is *strictly* increasing. Same for decreasing. The first part is easier: $\|p(\tau)\|=\tau\|p_u\|=a\tau$ where $a>0$ (if $g\ne 0$) - a linear function.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thank you for the reply. I do not understand. The second part is correct? While for the first part you suggest an easier way?

Comment: The second part is correct as the derivative being zero at one point does not affect strictly decreasing. The first part can be done easier - without squaring and differentiation, but it is up to you. Do not forget then to relate at the end $h$ being increasing with $\|p\|$ increasing.